# How to replace name with regex

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace `%username%` with any name inputted. I wanna replace that keeping the end part of the entire string `%username%, your Account Has Been Successfully Created!`

```html
<h2 class="done">%username%, your Account Has Been Successfully Created!</h2>
```

```js
let name = $(".done");
name.text().replace(/\%(.+?)\%/, this.value);
```

`this.value` is just the username inputted in the input field.

Comment: You are altering the string, it does not magically get applied back to the element. You need to set the element's text with the new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the replaced string back to the original variable, e.g.

```js
let name = $(".done");
name.text(name.text().replace(/%.+?%/, this.value));
```

Note that `%` is *not* a regex metacharacter, and so it does require any escaping with backslash.

Comment: I'm glad that it's working for you.